# Shell command to transfer files from HDFS to local filesystem in Hadoop 2.6.9

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to Hadoop. Is there a bash command to transfer files from the Hadoop distributed file system to the standard file system on a hadoop node.

I am using `Hadoop 2.6.0`

I saw another similar question which asks how to do the same in Java: [Copying files from HDFS to local file system with JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494304/copying-files-from-hdfs-to-local-file-system-with-java)

Can we do it with a simple shell command instead (which runs on a node that is part of the hadoop cluster)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy file from HDFS to the local file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837871/how-to-copy-file-from-hdfs-to-the-local-file-system)

Comment: Hmm, this looks like a possible duplicate, but I just checked that the commands in the answers there do not work. Looks like hdfs command works for `hadoop 2.6.0` and `bin/hadoop fs` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hdfs dfs -get /hdfs/path /local/path`

`hdfs dfs -put /local/path /hdfs/path`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull data down from HDFS to a local directory,you'll need to   use the -get or -copyToLocal switches to the hadoop fs command.

hadoop fs -copyToLocal  hdfs://path  localpath

just call the command in shell scripting.you can do something like below.

for line in `awk '/.csv/ {print $2}'  /user/hadoop/TempFiles/CLNewFiles.txt`;

do

hadoop fs copyToLocal  /user/hadoop/TempFiles/$line  yourlocalpath

echo "$line file is downloading from hadoop"

done